# text editor with variables dynamic angualrjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, text-editor

Hello everybody i want to Make like this text editor

[image]

with variables dynamic angularjs but i have any idea please tel me a name of a directive  [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0gyO.png) thanks :D

Comment: Looks like a WYSIWYG editor. Search for CKEditor or TinyMCE for example

Comment: Thanks ,My problem is just adding the placeholders to the text editor like(FirstName ,ALstName) and be dynamic when i use binding .. you understund me

Comment: @zakariaBouzangad, Can you brief me about how did you add the placeholder & how you connected with dynamic variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably existing directives for this, but here is a simple example:

```
app.directive("richEditor", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
        variables: "=",
        ngModel: "="
      },
      template: "<div>\
        <textarea ng-model='ngModel'></textarea>\
    <span ng-repeat='variable in variables' ng-click='varSelected(variable)'>{{ variable }}</span>\
    </div>",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var textarea = element.find("textarea");
        scope.varSelected = function(variable) {
          if (!scope.ngModel) {
            scope.ngModel = "";
          }
          var position = textarea[0].selectionStart;
          var val = scope.ngModel.substring(0, position) + variable + scope.ngModel.substring(position);
          scope.ngModel = val;
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fe7fduf6/)

Comment: Thanks, but its resolve 50% of my probleme i can also add a text editor and put your code ?